# Graphing a Parabola using Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to graph a simple parabola in `matplotlib` and I am confused as to how I am supposed to plot points on the parabola. So far, this is what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=[]
b=[]
y=0
x=-50
while x in range(-50,50,1):
    y=x^2+2*x+2
    a=[x]
    b=[y]
    fig= plt.figure()
    axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
    axes.plot(a,b)
    plt.show()
    x= x+1
```

Answer (score 16):

This should do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create 1000 equally spaced points between -10 and 10
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

# calculate the y value for each element of the x vector
y = x**2 + 2*x + 2  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image: mpl-plot]

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xval=[]
yval=[]
y=0
x=-50
while x in range(-50,51,1):
    y=x*x 
    xval.append(x)
    yval.append(y)
    x= x+1

print xval
print yval

plt.plot(xval,yval)
plt.show()

Answer (score 10):

This is your approach with as few changes as possible to make it work (because it's clear that you're a beginner and this is a learning exercise).  The changes I made were:

1. Moved the `plt.figure`, and other plotting statements out of the loop.  The loop now gives you the data to plot, and then you plot it once the loop is finished.
2. Changed `x^2` to `x**2`.
3. Changed `while` to `for` in your main loop control statement.
4. Commented out a few lines that weren't doing anything.  They all had the same source of error (or non-utility, really): in the for loop, `x` is set in the loop control line and then `y` is calculated directly, so you don't need to give them initial values or increment `x`, though you would have had to do these steps for a while loop.

[image]

Here the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[]
b=[]
# y=0
# x=-50

for x in range(-50,50,1):
    y=x**2+2*x+2
    a.append(x)
    b.append(y)
    #x= x+1

fig= plt.figure()
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Better than @cel's of course. It avoids using Numpy which steals execution time ...
BTW, `fig= plt.figure()` end `axes=fig.add_subplot(111)` are redundant. `axes = plt.gca()` is enough.

Comment: @Apostolos: thanks for the supportive comments, but I should be clear, that I was focusing on being instructive to the OP. Since OP wasn't using Numpy, I avoided it. Like, it shouldn't be Q: "How do I plot parabola?", A: "Learn Numpy", then, 1 year later, Q: "So how do I plot a parabola?" So these numpy answers here annoy me. But if I were doing this for myself, my code would look almost exactly like cel's. As for execution time, numpy becomes faster for large arrays, but even for smaller arrays the code is closer to the math expressions and more succinct, so I'd use it there too.

Comment: You did well abiding to the question requirements. You see, @cel didn't respect that, i.e. he used Numpy, and the result is that he got 50% more upvotes than you! This is why I believe that these upvotes are a joke!

Answer (score 3):

Hi there I think that you can use this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
'''
Set the values in the variable x
The function arange helps to generate an array with the 
following parameters arange(start,end,increment)
'''
x = np.arange(-100,100,1)
'''
Now set the formula in the variable y
'''
y = x**2
'''
Then add the pair (x,y) to the plot
'''
plt.plot(x,y)
'''
Finally show the graph
'''
plt.show()
```

[image: Parabola]

Comment: Much cleaner than the top answer

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your third to last line to:

```
axes.plot(a,b, 'r-^')
```

Adding the '`r-^`' will add red triangular points to the graph. Alternatively, you can use '`b-o`'.

**Note:** You should include the quotes.

For different colors you can use 'b' - blue; 'g' - green; 'r' - red; 'c' - cyan; 'm' - magenta; 'y' - yellow; 'k' - black; 'w' - white

The - in the '`r-^`' or '`b-o`' will create the line joining the triangles or circles respectively. That is, without the dash, you will end up with a scatter plot.

Alternatively, there is command ....`scatter(x,y)` which would be equivalent to '`r ^`' and '`b o`'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use list comprehension for that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt, pow
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Defining the range for the input values on the horizontal axis
x_values = [x for x in range(-50, 50)]

# Computiong the values of the quadratic equation for different values in x_values
y_values = [(pow(x,2)+4*x+4) for x in x_values]

ax.plot(x_values, y_values, linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[a graph generated by python using the library matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X6UB.png)