# Python Graphing a Parabola using Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

How can I build a graph using this function? Thanks! :) I tried, but I am getting confused how should I use: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553585/graphing-a-parabola-using-matplotlib-in-python#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553585/graphing-a-parabola-using-matplotlib-in-python#_=_)

```
def quadratic (a, b, c):
try:
    d = b**2-4*a*c
    convex_point = -b/(2*a)
    if(d == 0):
        convex_point = -b/(2*a) #it is the x-interceptor when det is 0 
        print('the convex point is at',convex_point, 'on the x-axis | the parabola intersect the y-axis at',c, '| the determinant is 0');
    elif(d < 0):
        print('Determinant is', d,'and if determinant is smaller than zero, there is no real solution');
    else:
        x_positive = (-b+ math.sqrt(d))/(2*a); # y = 0
        x_negative = (-b- math.sqrt(d))/(2*a); # y = 0
        print('the convex points is at',convex_point, 'on the x-axis |x_positive',x_positive,' |x_negative',x_negative,'| the parabola intersect the y-axis at',c)


except:
    print('try: import math');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def quadratic (a, b, c):
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import math
    import numpy as np
    d = b**2-4*a*c
    convex_point = -b/(2*a)
    x = np.linspace(-50, 50, 1000);
    y = a**2 + b*x + c
    fig, ax = plt.subplots();
    ax.plot(x, y)
    if(d == 0):
        convex_point = -b/(2*a) #it is the x-interceptor when det is 0
        print('the convex point is at',convex_point, 'on the x-axis | the parabola intersect the y-axis at',c, '| the determinant is 0');
    elif(d < 0):
        print('Determinant is', d,'and if determinant is smaller than zero, there is no real solution');
    else:
        x_positive = (-b+ math.sqrt(d))/(2*a); # y = 0
        x_negative = (-b- math.sqrt(d))/(2*a); # y = 0
        print('the convex points is at',convex_point, 'on the x-axis |x_positive',x_positive,' |x_negative',x_negative,'| the parabola intersect the y-axis at',c);



except:
    print('try: import math')
```

except it does not show the graph :S

Comment: try adding a `plt.show()` in there after your `ax.plot` line

Comment: I tried but it throw me an exception, when I deleted it, it was ok again.

Comment: Thanks, solved I was mistakenly doing ax.show instead of plt.show ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
def quadratic (a, b, c):
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import math
    import numpy as np
    d = b**2-4*a*c
    convex_point = -b/(2*a)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000);
    y = a**2 + b*x + c
    fig, ax = plt.subplots();
    ax.plot(x, y);
    plt.show()
    if(d == 0):
        convex_point = -b/(2*a) #it is the x-interceptor when det is 0
        print('the convex point is at',convex_point, 'on the x-axis | the parabola intersect the y-axis at',c, '| the determinant is 0');
    elif(d < 0):
        print('Determinant is', d,'and if determinant is smaller than zero, there is no real solution');
    else:
        x_positive = (-b+ math.sqrt(d))/(2*a); # y = 0
        x_negative = (-b- math.sqrt(d))/(2*a); # y = 0
        print('the convex points is at',convex_point, 'on the x-axis |x_positive',x_positive,' |x_negative',x_negative,'| the parabola intersect the y-axis at',c);
except:
    print('try: import math')
```

This code work :)